# How get the position of an element in a bst recursive ?? in O(h) runtime

Tags: data-structures, binary-search-tree

I need to get the position of an element of a bst. This is the struct that I am using, numSubtree (is to get track of how many nodes are in the subtree).

```
struct bst_node {
      int      val;
      int    numSubtree;
      bst_node *left;
      bst_node *right;

};
```

for example, if a call position_of(number) it should return me the index 1,2,3..etc
so far i have tried this

```
 int _position_of(bst_node *t, T x, int count){

          if (t->left != nullptr) {
               count = t->left->numNodesSub + 1;
          }else {
                count = 1;  
          }

          if (t->val == x) {
            return count;
          }
            
          if (x < t->val ) {
            return _position_of(t->left, x, count);
          }

          //otherwise 
          return _position_of(t->right, x, count + 1);

      }
```

Comment: You have to check if `t` is null in the beginning of the function, because you pass a possibly null pointer when you do `_position_of(t->right, x, count + 1);`

Answer (score 0):

Given a `bst_node *node` and an element `x` we want to find the number of elements `<= x`. There are four cases to consider:

- If the node is null, there are no elements `<= x`, so return 0.
- If `node->val < x`, `node` and the `node->right` subtree are `> x`, so find the position on the `root->left`.
- If `node->val > x`, `node` and the `node->left` subtree are `<= x`, so add 1 + left subtree size to the result of finding the position on the right side.
- Otherwise, if `node->val == x`, only `node` and the `node->left` subtree are `<= x`, so simply return 1 + left subtree size.

```c
// Returns the number of elements <= `x` in the binary search tree rooted at `node`.
int position(bst_node *node, T x) {
    if (!node) {
        return 0;
    }

    if (node->val < x) {
        return position(node->left, x);
    } 

    bst_node* left_node = node->left;
    int left_subtree_size = 0;
    if (node->left) {
        left_subtree_size = node->left->numSubtree;
    }

    if (node->val > x) {
        return 1 + left_subtree_size + position(node->right, x);
    } else {
        return 1 + left_subtree_size;
    }
}
```

Comment: I implemented that solution but it is giving me the wrong position

Comment: @LuisLema that's surprising. Can you please provide an example test case along with the expected and actual output?